# what is the nuget lib folder for uwp

Tags: nuget, uwp

I have a nuget package, and I want to add uwp version of it,
usually I would drop the dll in `lib/net40`
I would like to know where to drop the dll for uwp,
this is the project.json file for the uwp project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DLL generally targets all Windows Store Platforms (WinRT 8.0, 8.1, UWP for Windows 10), put it in `lib/netcore`. If it's designed specifically for Windows 10 and uses UWP APIs, put it in `lib/uap` or `lib/uap10.0`.

Check out [the Nuget docs for creating UWP packages](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/uwp-create), and the section *New Target Frameworks* in [this Nuget blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html)!

EDIT: What you should *not* do is, put any DLL directly in the `lib/` folder. In previous versions, all libraries in `lib` would have been used for all platforms that don't have any specific DLL assigned, while in UWP they are simply ignored.